Extensions of $G$-modules parametrized by $H^1$
Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and let $V$, $W$ be one-dimensional representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. (I guess we can think of $V$ and $W$ simply as $G$-modules, which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_q$ as $\mathbb{F}_q$ vector spaces)
Up to scalars, equivalence of extensions
\begin{equation}
  0\to W \to E \to V\to 0
\end{equation}
are parametrized by $\operatorname{Ext}^1_G(V,W):=H^1(\operatorname{Hom}(F',W)^{G})$ where $F'\to V$ is a projective resolution of $V$ over $\mathbb{Z}G$ and $(-)^G$ is the invariants functor.
I am tempted to claim that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_G(V,W) = H^1(G,V^{\vee}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} W)$, the group cohomology of $G$, with coefficients in $V^{\vee}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} W$. The only way I could see it, is to take $F\to \mathbb{Z}$ to be a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}G$, tensor it with $V$ to obtain a "projective resolution" of $V$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{Ext}^1_G(V,W) = H^1(\operatorname{Hom}(F\otimes V,W)^{G})\\\\
        = H^1(\operatorname{Hom}(F,Hom (V,W))^{G})\\\\
        = H^1(G,\operatorname{Hom}(V,W))\\\\
        = H^1(G,V^{\vee}\otimes_{\mathbb Z}W)\\\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
But the part in bold above is incorrect I believe, so I don't know if the claim is incorrect, if there is a another way to prove it, or if there is a more correct way to obtain a projective resolution of $V$ from a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$.
Thanks for your help.
P.S. I have seen similar questions in different contexts, like here, but it seems that the condition that $V$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-free is necessary for the claim to be true, which is not the case for $V\cong \mathbb{F}_q$.
Edit
I took invariants in the above parametrization of equivalences of extensions because I work in the category of $G$-representations, so morphisms of representations should be $G$-equivariant, that is, for any $u\in Hom(F',W), f'\in F'$, we have $u(g^{-1}\cdot f') = g^{-1}\cdot u(f')$. Multiplying by $g$ on both sides, we get $g\cdot u(g^{-1}\cdot f') = u(f')$. So we see that the morphisms in our category are the invariants by the action $(g\cdot u)(f') = g\cdot (u(g^{-1}\cdot f'))$. Here we see both $F'$ and $W$ as left $G$-modules, and the inverses take into account the contravariance of $Hom$ in the first variable and the covariance in the second variable.

I don't think you should take invariants there. If you just think of $G$ modules as $\Bbb ZG$ modules then $\mathsf{Ext}^1_{\Bbb ZG}(V; W)=H^1\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbb ZG}(F',W)$ without any invariants

Thank you, actually I edited the question to say why I took invariants. I think that if I look at $\mathsf{Hom}_{\Bbb ZG}(F',W)
$, maybe that will include morphisms of modules which are not necessarily morphisms of $G$-representations. But please correct me if I am wrong
